# Is this the wrong site for this question?

Tags: support

I asked a [question](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/34551/16438) which received one down vote with no explanation, and one frivolous, waste of time comment.  It is a very important question for me, for something I am writing on deadline.  I am thinking of deleting the question and posting a reframed version on ELU, where I am a regular participant.  But I thought I would ask advice from those in the know on History SE first.

I asked the question here because it relates to the history of World War I.  Is there anything wrong with the question? If so, please help me fix it.  I noticed this site is in Beta.  ELU is a well establish site with lots of participation.  Might I do better there even though there is a historical aspect to the question, because perhaps History SE has a lower readership?

Comment: As someone who hangs on ELU a bit, I'd be surprised if they kept it open there.

Answer (score 1):

I can't (and in fact, often don't) speak for anyone else here, but it looks on-topic to me.

Due to the Holidays, I don't have a lot of time to research it myself (so I have not posted an answer). Could be that others are in the same boat. I'll go post a comment there, until such time as someone can research a proper answer.

For the record, a StackExchange site in "beta" these days essentially means it doesn't (yet) regularly receive more than about 10 new questions a day. We're perhaps on the higher end of that, but that's where we are. In fact, our numbers are roughly similar to what you'll see on a lot of the smaller "graduated" sites that graduated under the old rules (eg:Skeptics).